# Chainable modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, chaining

I am new to node.js. I have created this module so far.

```
module.exports = function() {

    var groups = [];

    var Group = function(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.users = [];
    };

    return {
        create: function(id) {
            var group = new Group(id);
            groups.push(group);
        },
        find: function(id) {
            var group = groups.find((element, index, array) => {
                return element.id === id;
            });
            return group ? group : null;
        },
        findIndex: function(id)  {
            var index = groups.findIndex((element, i, array) => {
                return element.id === id;
            });
            return index;
        },
        getAll: function() {
            return groups;
        },
        users: function(id) {
            var group = this.find(id);
            return group ? group.users : [];
        }
    };

};
```

I can use the module like this:

```
var groups = require('./groups')();
groups.create(12);
console.log(groups.getAll());
```

etc.

But I like to implement same structure to `users` in `groups` so that I can call like `groups.find(12).users.add(user_id, 'some user')` or `groups.find(12).users.remove(user_id)` etc.

How can I achieve that? Please help.

Comment: is not the above not working?

Comment: It is working. But the methods are applicable (or working) on the `groups` array defined in the module. What I want is to define another set of methods which will work on the `users` array of each `group` object (instance).